# How to get JobInfo2 from WinspoolUtil and Winspool using JNA (Printers and Jobs)?

Tags: java, jna

I think I can use something like this:

```
for(JOB_INFO_2 ji2: WinspoolUtil.getJobInfo2(phPrinter)){
// ... 

}
```

API JNA that uses `Winspool.drv` to obtain such information is [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/3f4fb37611715076941dd105fe7c11e21932c1e6/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32). But it is incomplete.

For example there I can't find this method: 
`WinspoolUtil.getJobInfo2(?)`
where "?" is something that I don't know.

Comment: Is your printer local, remote, or a domain printer? Will all clients which run your program have the printer added or will you want to search the remote/domain printers for a specific printer? Are you trying to get the job infos of *all* printers?

Comment: Hi, cubrr. Lets say I want to run some script like that in a machine that concentrates all printers available. There is no extranet, but exist a domain(intranet) where cellphones, notebooks, tablets and desktop pcs make request to print some job to some printer. 
Get all job info from all printers in domain. 
P.S.: Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Me too @user3461158, I wonder if i could call the getJobInfo2() beacuse i need to obtain pDevMode pointer to get the 'number of copies' of currently printing works. :')

Answer (score 2):

The `WinspoolUtil` and other Windows API mappings provided by JNA can be found in the [`jna-platform`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform) artifact.

It would appear like JNA does [not have](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.html#getJobInfo1-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference-) a ready-made mapping for getting level 2 info of a print job. You can use [`WinspoolUtil#getJobInfo1`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.html#getJobInfo1-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference-) if you do not need the detailed information that the level 2 structure provides. This function uses the `Winspool.drv` [`EnumJobs` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx), whose documentation says this:

> The [`JOB_INFO_1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145019(v=vs.85).aspx) structure contains general print-job information; the [`JOB_INFO_2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145020(v=vs.85).aspx) structure has much more detailed information. The [`JOB_INFO_3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145021(v=vs.85).aspx) structure contains information about how jobs are linked.

As for how to get the handle to the printer, you'll first need to *enumerate the printers*, then *open the printer*, then *enumerate the jobs*.

## Printer enumeration

If you know the exact name of the printer, you can skip this step completely.

The enumeration of the printers depends on how the printer you're looking for is connected (local/remote/domain) and what level of details you need (see [*Remarks*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692(v=vs.85).aspx)).

- If you just want a fast and easy way to get minimal information (attributes, printer name, server name) of locally and remotely connected printers from the registry, use [`WinspoolUtil.getAllPrinterInfo4()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.html#getPrinterInfo4--).
- If you want to get detailed information of all connected printers and/or want to also check their statuses, you'll want to use [`WinspoolUtil.getAllPrinterInfo2()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.html#getPrinterInfo2--). Note though that *this may take a while*; the documentation of EnumPrinters says that with 2 as the level, it will call [OpenPrinter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751(v=vs.85).aspx) on every remote printer and it will have to wait for the time out to tell that the printer is *not* available.

  Alternatively, if you want level 2 information but only of *locally connected printers*, use `WinspoolUtil.getPrinterInfo2()`.
- Additionally, there's `getPrinterInfo1()` but JNA only seems to get the local printers - I'm not sure how its performance or its details compare to `getPrinterInfo4()`.

#### Example: Print the names of all printers found in the registry

```
Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4[] printers = WinspoolUtil.getPrinterInfo4();

System.out.println("Printers:");
for (Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4 printer : printers) {
    System.out.println("  Name: " + printer.pPrinterName + ", server: " + printer.pServerName);
}
```

## Opening the printer

Once you've enumerated the printers and have identified the printer with which you want to work with, you can use [`Winspool#OpenPrinter`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Winspool.html#OpenPrinter-java.lang.String-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Winspool.LPPRINTER_DEFAULTS-) to open a handle to the printer. This call may fail if you don't have permissions to the printer.

Always remember to call [`Winspool#ClosePrinter`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Winspool.html#ClosePrinter-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE-) when done with the printer.

#### Example: Open a handle to a printer

```
Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4[] printers = WinspoolUtil.getPrinterInfo4();
System.out.println("Opening printer \"" + printers[0].pPrinterName + "\".");

WinNT.HANDLEByReference phPrinter = new WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
boolean ok = Winspool.INSTANCE.OpenPrinter(printers[0].pPrinterName, phPrinter, null);
System.out.println("ok = " + ok);
Winspool.INSTANCE.ClosePrinter(phPrinter.getValue());
```

## Job enumeration

Now that you have a handle to the printer, you can use [`WinspoolUtil#getJobInfo1`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.html#getJobInfo1-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference-) to get the jobs. However, this will only get you the general print-job information as you can read from the Remarks section of the [`EnumJobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

#### Example: Print all the jobs of a printer

```
Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4[] printers = WinspoolUtil.getPrinterInfo4();
// Just an example - get the first printer from the list
Winspool.PRINTER_INFO_4 printer = printers[4];

WinNT.HANDLEByReference phPrinter = new WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
boolean opened = Winspool.INSTANCE.OpenPrinter(
    printer.pPrinterName,
    phPrinter,
    null
);

if (!opened) {
    System.err.printf("Failed to open printer \"%s\"!", printer.pPrinterName);
    return;
}

Winspool.JOB_INFO_1[] jobs = WinspoolUtil.getJobInfo1(phPrinter);
System.out.printf("Printer \"%s\" has %d jobs\n", printer.pPrinterName, jobs.length);
for (Winspool.JOB_INFO_1 job : jobs) {
    System.out.printf(
        "  Document: \"%s\", owner: %s, status: %s, total pages: %d, pages printed: %d ...\n",
        job.pDocument,
        job.pUserName,
        job.pStatus != null ? job.pStatus : job.Status,
        job.TotalPages,
        job.PagesPrinted
    );
}

Winspool.INSTANCE.ClosePrinter(phPrinter.getValue());
```

This example produces the following output for me:

> Printer "EPSONA78A80 (L355 Series)" has 1 jobs
>
> Document: "java - How to make GetLastError reliably work with JNA? - Stack Overflow", owner: pc, status: 0, total pages: 1, pages printed: 0 ...

In closing, the Windows API has a whole bunch of ways to enumerate printers and jobs, depending on what level of information you need and from which printers. JNA only has mappings for some of the methods, but I think that if you really really need those level 2 job info details, you can just take a look at the [source of `WinspoolUtil#getJobInfo1`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/028fff09fd473e2fe0fae8d781d2f754fe13daac/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinspoolUtil.java#L154) and the documentation of [`EnumJobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx) to figure it out.

Additionally, if you're interested in monitoring for changes in a specific printer's spool, take a look at the ["w32printer" example](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/ea9de70cb73ca0794120666e8ed9794d88ea5c81/contrib/w32printing/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32SpoolMonitor.java) in JNA's Github repository.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation @cbr... But what if we need to obtain the number of copies of currently running printjob ? Where did it come from...?